# Tweek x Craig - Japanese people deciding who is homosexual

Tags: south-park

In the beginning of the episode we see Wendy Testaburger talking about Yaoi. She presents the pictures of Tweek and Craig shown as a homosexual couple. Afterwards the pupils start to discuss why the Asian girls have shown them as a couple although they weren't gay and they aren't a couple.

At the end of the episode, Craig's father talks to him about being gay and "deciding" to be gay or not. He says "You don't get to decide, Japan picks who they pick.".
I never heard of a prejudice about Japanese people who would "make" somebody gay, so I don't understand this reference.

Where does this come from?

Answer (score 6):

Craig's father isn't voicing a stereotype. He's comically making a completely wrong conclusion based on the show's events. Basically:

- The asian girls drew Japanese art. Lets assume for now that the girls are Japanese, since Craig's father does.
- They chose to depict Tweek and Craig as a gay couple.
- Because of this, Tweek and Craig are assumed to be a gay couple in reality. This is the main plot point, that this is blindly taken to be true by everyone.
- No matter how much Craig fought it, he could not change people's blind assumption that he is gay.

Condensing this into Craig's father's advice, the choice the Japanese girls made (to depict them as a gay couple) made it to be the commonly accepted truth that Craig is gay. Craig could not alter this, the Japanese girls' decision is what set this course of events.

---

I don't remember if this is revealed in the episode as well, but in the South Park game The Fractured But Whole, Craig's dad is shown to be an avid yaoi collector. This can help support why he takes the depictions of yaoi very seriously and does not question their content.